# Webservice Callout Exception: IO Exception: Read timed out

Tags: soap, callout, exception, wsdl, future

I have Salesforce trigger that triggers either a future method or batch job that does call outs to a SOAP webservice.

I am randomly getting "(IO Exception: Read timed out)" exception. When the timeout issue started happening this past few days I also received 2 other exceptions:

> IO exception: Read timed out
>
> (Web service callout failed: Unexpected element. Parser was expecting element 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/:Envelope' but found ':html').

The webservice works most of the time but the timeout issue happens randomly. and it only happen to selective webservices not all. but all webservice program is located in the same server

the Webserver already included all the whitelisted IP from Salesforce

I try a sample request using SOAPUI to do a test it end up working fine.

I have no idea why it is happening.

Comment: It would appear the the web service it failing in some way and returning an HTML error page instead of a valid SOAP response. Try capturing the debug log and looking for the complete request/response messages.

Comment: How to capture request/response messages? where the only error response message I receive is ->  (Web service callout failed: Unexpected element. Parser was expecting element 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/:Envelope' but found ':html').

Comment: Run the test with the developer console open. Then open the corresponding log from the Logs tab to the bottom left.

Comment: EXCEPTION_THROWN [121]|System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: Unexpected element. Parser was expecting element 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/:Envelope' but found ':html' this is what I get from my log~

Comment: It's the lines immediately before that where the useful information will be. If you can reproduce the same outbound SOAP request with something like SOAP UI then you will likely see the same result. Most likely the Server is sending back an HTML error page to Salesforce.

Comment: Yup I did that. As mention while testing via SOUPUI no problem. but only salesforce hitting the error

Comment: If the failure is intermittent and a one off request from SOAPUI works then it is more likely an issue with the web service. It will be failing and returning an HTML error page. You could switch to making [HttpRequest](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_http_httprequest.htm) calls to the same API if you want to see the full response.